# How to properly configure OpenIddict with ASP.NET Core DataProtection

Tags: openid-connect, openiddict

I am trying to setup OpenIddict using ASP.NET Core DataProtection however I keep getting an exception when attempting to start the application:

`InvalidOperationException: At least one encryption key must be registered in the OpenIddict server options. Consider registering a certificate using 'services.AddOpenIddict().AddServer().AddEncryptionCertificate()' or 'services.AddOpenIddict().AddServer().AddDevelopmentEncryptionCertificate()' or call 'services.AddOpenIddict().AddServer().AddEphemeralEncryptionKey()' to use an ephemeral key.`

Now I understand what the error wants me to do, I need to add a signing key/encryption certificate, but why?

Isn't the whole point of using the DataProtection that this part is automated and doesn't require you to add an explicit signing key/encryption certificate?
According to the documentation the DataProtection should be used to encrypt all the keys except for JWT id tokens.

This is the current code:

```cs
            if (authenticationOptions.DataProtection.TokenProtection.Enabled)
                services
                    .AddDataProtection(options =>
                    {
                        options.ApplicationDiscriminator = applicationOptions.ShortName;
                    })
                    .SetApplicationName(applicationOptions.Name)
                    .SetDefaultKeyLifetime(TimeSpan.FromDays(authenticationOptions.DataProtection.TokenProtection.LifeTime))
                    .PersistKeysToAzureBlobStorage(CreateDataProtectionBlobClient(azureOptions.BlobStorageUrl, authenticationOptions.DataProtection, azureCredential))
                    .ProtectKeysWithAzureKeyVault(completeKeyVaultUri, azureCredential);
            }

            services.AddOpenIddict()
                .AddCore(options =>
                {
                    options.UseEntityFrameworkCore()
                        .UseDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>()
                        .ReplaceDefaultEntities<long>(); ;
                })
                .AddServer(options =>
                {
                    options.SetAuthorizationEndpointUris("connect/auth");
                    options.SetTokenEndpointUris("/connect/token");

                    options.AllowAuthorizationCodeFlow();
                    options.AllowClientCredentialsFlow();
                    options.AllowRefreshTokenFlow();

                    options.UseAspNetCore()
                        .EnableAuthorizationEndpointPassthrough()
                        .EnableTokenEndpointPassthrough();

                    options.UseDataProtection();
                    //options.AddEphemeralSigningKey();
                    //options.AddEphemeralEncryptionKey();
                })
                .AddValidation(options =>
                {
                    options.UseLocalServer();
                    options.UseAspNetCore();
                    options.UseDataProtection();
                });
```

Comment: Have you managed to find out the answer to this? Thanks!

Comment: @igorsp7 Unfortunately not, there does not seem to be an easy way to do this so I'm in the process of extending OpenIddict so that keys can be loaded using custom provider classes

Answer (score 3):

The data protection API is involved inside the Cookie handler, and its job is to encrypt the session cookie. The session cookie contains the ClaimsPrincipal User object and optionally your tokens.

Just like this picture shows:

[image]

By default the Data Protection API creates its own key-ring and that's great! But in production you want to make sure the keyring stays the same across deployments. If not, if you redeploy, then you might not be able to accept previously generated cookies.

I did blog about this here:
https://www.edument.se/post/storing-the-asp-net-core-data-protection-key-ring-in-azure-key-vault?lang=en

However, the Data Protection API is not involved in managing the token signing keys. Data Protection is only about protecting the session cookie. So you need to provide a separate private key (persisted externally), so the key is the same across deployments of your service.

Data Protection API is only about protecting things, not what to protect. So that's why you need a separate key/certificate.

I did a blog post about how you can bypass the protection and peek inside the cookies at: https://nestenius.se/2023/11/22/exploring-what-is-inside-the-asp-net-core-cookies/

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have my Data Protection API working, that isn't the issue. I already have it configured using Azure Blob Storage/Key Vault. I only have an issue integrating it with OpenIddict

Comment: see my updated question, does it clarify/help?

Comment: No this is not the issue, OpenIddict provides a "UseDataProtection()" method in the options builder to be able to build access tokens etc using the DataProtection API: [Source](https://github.com/openiddict/openiddict-core/blob/dev/src/OpenIddict.Server.DataProtection/OpenIddictServerDataProtectionHandlers.Protection.cs#L188). However the options builder still requires me to provide a signing key/certificate which I think shouldn't be required.

Comment: In many organizations, the signing key is an important thing and you want to enforce various policies, like key rotation. Yes and I think it good that Data Protection API just focus on one task, encrypting data and managing its own key/key-ring. And it does not care about what it handles.  Similar o the HTTPS certificate, you need to provide one separately as well...

Comment: In OpenIDConnect you have also multiple key types, RSA and 3 types of ECDSA, so in your opinion, The data protection would have to understand all of that as well. So separating the responsibility  simplifies the data protection api.

Comment: But what if you wanted to provide key rollover to this main key, or is this not required?
Right now it seems very much completely static and unable to be changed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240072/discussion-between-thodor20-and-tore-nestenius).

Comment: the Data Protection key ring has its own "key-rotation" where it internally rotates the key by default every 90 days. It remembers old keys so that "old" data still can be decrypted. It always encrypts with the latest key. Same for singing keys, you keep the old key so that existing tokens can be "verified" (if needed).

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is, using `UseDataProtection` does not replace the need for the certificates, so commenting out the lines:

```
                //options.AddEphemeralSigningKey();
                //options.AddEphemeralEncryptionKey();
```

means you don't have a certificate, hence the error thrown by OpenIddict.

You can store both your Data Protection Key and your Certificate in Azure (e.g. Blob & Key Vault). You just have to do all the configuration for both.

(Like the OP, I also thought adding the `.UseDataProtection()` with the key persisted in Azure meant I could remove the certificate - but alas, no... they are two completely different things)